# Trouble understanding what this question is asking.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> An automorphism on a group $G$  is a mapping $\Phi:G\to G$ which is one-to-one, onto and has the property that $\Phi(a\cdot b)=\Phi(a)\cdot\Phi(b)$ for all $a,b \in G$.
>
> Show that if $G$ is Abelian, then the map $\Phi:G\to G$ defined by $\phi(a)=a^{-1}$ for each $a\in G$, is a group automorphism.

I believe this question is wanting me to proof something, but I don't know what I am proving in the second line. Nor do I understand what format they are asking for.

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tell us just what part you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

What are you getting stuck on? You get a definition, and must verify that the function $\phi$ provided fits the definition provided.

1. Is your $\phi$ a map $G \to G$?
2. Is it a bijection?
3. Does $\phi$ satisfy $\phi(a*b) = \phi(a)*\phi(b)\ \forall a,b \in G$?

**UPDATE**

A *map* $G \to G$ is a function that takes elements from $G$ and returning elements of $G$. In our case, certainly, since $(G,*)$ is a group, we know that for each $g \in G$, there exists a unique $g^{-1} \in G$. Thus, the relation $f:G \to G$ given by $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ is well-defined. To check that it's a function, you need to make sure that $\phi$ maps each $x$ to exactly one element of $G$, and the uniqueness of the inverse guarantees that, so indeed our $\phi$ is a function and is $G \to G$, so the first question is definitely satisfied.

Comment: 1. This would be the main part I don't understand. As map is a new concept for me an the teacher hasn't gone over it in class at all.
2. yes it is a bijection due to the induction statement.
3. I believe it does due to the abelian property.

Comment: @Jamjack see update on question #1 above